# How to call Submit from Credential Provider

Tags: windows, authentication, credential-providers

As far as I could understand, when the user presses the Submit button eventually, the `GetSerialization` method will be called to get login details.

I am programming a Credential Provider that waits for some external signal to log in, and I do not want the user to press the Submit button.

Is it possible to trigger the submit event from the Credential Provider?

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do it. The trick is not to call the `submit` button, but use the `ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged` method. I have a thread running, that will eventually trigger the `CredentialsChanged`. This will then enable a new Credential that logs the user in.

This is shown in the Microsoft Sample `SampleHardwareEventCredentialProvider`.

It is worth notice that the Windows LogonUI automatically selects this new Credential. I do not know if this is in the documentation, but it is the behaviour I experienced.

Comment: Do you have this thread running in a separate service or did you start a thread within your custom credential provider? When I try to wait for an external signal within a polling thread in my credential provider ,the UI starts flickering as if it reloads the credential provider on every loop.

Comment: I start a new thread waiting for the external signal which then calls `CredentialsChanged`.

Flickering and reloading, in my experience, means that some invalid access happened (or other error). It would be useful for you to run in a debugger. The way I do this is by running a separate program that basically creates the COM object using `CoCreateInstance` and calling the `ICredentialProvider` methods.

Comment: Thanks @cd611, I'll try.

Comment: Sorry for late responds, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908444/16980671) will gonna help you

Comment: @cd611 Have you got it working for multiple users?

Answer (score 2):

The more appropriate way would be to implement the [IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-iconnectablecredentialprovidercredential) interface, which is designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Doc says  IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential::Connect() gets called after user clicks Submit button. Can you please elaborate on how this interface should be implemented so that it simulates submit button click. Thanks

Comment: This is not possible afaik. The user would press the signin button which will be displayed when no other fields have been added to the cp, then the asynchronous process would begin ie making a remote call. When this call resolves you now have the opportunity to serialise the credential given that you have a password etc to serialise