# Can I create a CommandLink that works the same as the submit button?

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

Please understand my lack of writing skills.

I am testing to make a custom credential provider.
I want to create a `CommandLink` that does the same thing with the submit button.
I want to log on through the `CommandLink` separately from the Submit button.
Currently, only the custom credential provider is exposed through the `providerFilter::Filter(CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus, DWORD dwFlags, GUID* rgclsidProviders, BOOL* rgbAllow, DWORD cProviders)`.
[image]
Click [anathor longon button] to log on.

This is my sample code:

```
 HRESULT CSampleCredential::CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)
 {
     HRESULT hr = S_OK;
     DWORD dwResult = 0;

     if (dwFieldID < ARRAYSIZE(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors) &&
         (CPFT_COMMAND_LINK == _rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[dwFieldID].cpft))
     {
         HWND hwndOwner = nullptr;
         switch (dwFieldID)
         {
         case SFI_ANATHOR_SUBMIT_LINK:
             dwResult = function_foo();
             if(dwResult == 1) { 
                  Call GetSerialization()...?
                  Run the logon.
             }
             break;
             // ...
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are writing credential provider, than you are already implementing `ICredentialProvider` interface and its `Advise` method:

```
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Advise( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        _In_  ICredentialProviderEvents *pcpe,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        _In_  UINT_PTR upAdviseContext) = 0;
```

The first argument is pointer to events interface `ICredentialProviderEvents` which have only one method: `CredentialsChanged`.
Your task is to grab credentials from user (login/password) store them inside your internals and call this method.
On the next turn your provider will be called this method:

```
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetCredentialCount( 
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        _Out_  DWORD *pdwCount,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        _Out_  DWORD *pdwDefault,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        _Out_  BOOL *pbAutoLogonWithDefault) = 0;
```

Your task is to return the correct values in `pdwDefault` and `pbAutoLogonWithDefault` parameters (my suggest is `0` and `TRUE`).
Than your class that implementing `ICredentialProviderCredential` interface will be immediately called for `GetSerialization` method.

Here you can return already stored credentials.

Comment: Your friendly explanation has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Newbie here,

For the people who don't understand @Alexander 's explanation (like me several days ago), I recommend to read the [Sample Harware Event Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/security/credentialproviders/samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider). You need the 3rd class that is not inherited from `ICredentialProvider` or `ICredentialProviderCredential`. This is an independent class which is not related to both of them. I use this class to call the `CredentialsChanged` function.

So, TL;DR this is how I implement it:

1. Make a condition inside the `ICredentialProvider`'s `GetCredentialCount` function like this

```
HRESULT CSampleCredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount(
    DWORD* pdwCount,
    DWORD* pdwDefault,
    BOOL* pbAutoLogonWithDefault
)
{   
    //SavedCredentialInfo is just a simple Bool variable
    if (_pCredential->SavedCredentialInfo == true)
    {
        *pdwCount = 1;
        *pdwDefault = 0;
        *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = TRUE;
    }else{
        *pdwCount = 1;
        *pdwDefault = 0;
        *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;
    }

    return S_OK;

}
```

2. Save the credential (I use username & password) as a variable (string) inside my custom class that inherit `ICredentialProviderCredential`

```
HRESULT CGuardianCredential::CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)
{
    if (dwFieldID < ARRAYSIZE(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors) &&
        (CPFT_COMMAND_LINK == _rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[dwFieldID].cpft)) {
       
        this._username = "Ramon";
        this._domain = "DESKTOP-937SDJ";
        this._password = "MyPassword";
    }

    . . .
}
```

3. Call the 3rd class's function that call the `ICredentialProvider`'s `CredentialsChanged` function

```
HRESULT CGuardianCredential::CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)
{
    . . . 

    _commandWindow->callOnChange();
}
```

Then inside the commandWindow's class

```
BOOL CCommandWindow::callOnChange()
{
    _pProvider->OnConnectStatusChanged();
    return true;
}
```

Then you have it

Comment: This works fine with single user. How do we achieve this with multiple users?

Comment: @HNR If you are trying to do this in multiple users, please learn about writing & reading files on C:/System32 (or else with `System` privilege). It's been a while since I quit the company that works on this one. But that's what I've done back then. So I wrote the username, password, and domain combination and store it there.